# Retrieve Azure AccessedAt Value through REST

Tags: c#, rest, azure, servicebus

I'm trying to retrieve the "AccessedAt" value from the "QueueDescription" in Windows Azure Service Bus.

The code to retrieve it through the .NET libs look like this:

```
TokenProvider credentials = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider("owner", "[SECRET]");
NamespaceManager namespaceClient = new NamespaceManager(new Uri("https://[NAMESPACE].servicebus.windows.net/"), credentials);
QueueDescription q = namespaceClient.GetQueue("[QUEUE]");
```

Notice that the above is HTTP communication. It ought to be the same as REST.
One can do the same with the simple REST interface. See this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh416754.aspx

But when you do it with REST you get this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
   <id>https://[NAMESPACE].windows.net/[QUEUE]</id>
   <title type="text">[QUEUE]</title>
   <published>2014-03-25T14:31:36Z</published>
   <updated>2014-03-25T14:31:36Z</updated>
   <author>
      <name>[NAMESPACE]</name>
   </author>
   <link rel="self" href="https://[NAMESPACE].servicebus.windows.net/[QUEUE]" />
   <content type="application/xml">
      <QueueDescription xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <LockDuration>PT1M</LockDuration>
         <MaxSizeInMegabytes>1024</MaxSizeInMegabytes>
         <RequiresDuplicateDetection>false</RequiresDuplicateDetection>
         <RequiresSession>false</RequiresSession>
         <DefaultMessageTimeToLive>P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S</DefaultMessageTimeToLive>
         <DeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration>false</DeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration>
         <DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow>PT10M</DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow>
         <MaxDeliveryCount>10</MaxDeliveryCount>
         <EnableBatchedOperations>true</EnableBatchedOperations>
         <SizeInBytes>0</SizeInBytes>
         <MessageCount>0</MessageCount>
      </QueueDescription>
   </content>
</entry>
```

No "AccessedAt" value. I cannot find the difference between the two methods. 
I'm using this on a non PC. Hence the need of the REST api. I've tried digging through the Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll to see if it's a header or something that's missing. And there *are* some more headers added but they don't seem to make a difference. Or perhaps I haven't found the right one. (The Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll is not very transparent.)

Anyone knows how to get the "AccessedAt" value through REST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Service Bus REST API has a query parameter "api-version", can you try to pass in ?api-version="2014-01" and see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: It's working! (I had to leave out the ". Eg. api-version=2014-01) Priceless!